# What can we do with the visualization/understanding of the deep neural network

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, deep-learning

As far as I know, there is subfield of deep learning that attempt to use gradient to understand what a deep network is learning (e.g., what a filter is detecting). My question is after we know what they are learning, what can do we with those new information (e.g., change architecture design, etc)? Is there any literature on that?

A good Stanford video about visualization deep network.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wcs6szJWMY

Comment: Well for starters, you have the ability to transfer features between problems. Specifically, taking the convolutional kernels learned in one problem, and using them as initial conditions for another problem. This is especially universal for the first few convolutional layers, but then can diverge since higher level features will vary.

Comment: @AlexR. exactly. But, it would be more useful to interpret deep layer features and how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that can be done with these tools

- Checking whether your model's weights make sense when you suspect a bug
- Validating that your model doesn't just fit to random noise
- Extracting useful features for different models
- Compare different models when their performance is similar

I'm by no means an expert on the topic, but it seems like machine learning models interpretability is an active topic - for example you can check out [eli5](http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or techniques mentioned in this [repository](https://github.com/h2oai/mli-resources).

Comment: Great. I will check it out. This topic is interesting.